# Code::Blocks command line argument issues

Tags: c, command-line, arguments, codeblocks

Using:

- Code::Blocks Software
- Teach Yourself C book

None of "command line argument" example programs work. They either crash or execute with all variables with `0` value or show similar results to the program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return 0;
}
```

The simplest of the example program is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;

  for(i=1; i<argc; i++) printf("%s ", arv[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

With a bit of googling I have found that I need to have a `Project` as a `Console Application` and then use `Project -> set programs arguments`, but I have no idea of what to do in the window that pops up.

Comment: You write your arguments, one by one and separated by space, in the text box?

Comment: Here I can select Debug or Release, 2 check boxes and path to Host application. I added "argc argv" in the Program Arguments text box under Debug and left everything else untouched. Program crashes when run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have compiled your project as a console application, you can pass arguments by calling the program from the console (cmd.exe in Windows, terminal in Linux).
The window Project -> set programs arguments simply asks you what arguments do you want to pass to the program when you run the program from Code::Blocks (using the green arrow).
Simply add your arguments in the "Program arguments" text box.

Comment: Here I can select Debug or Release, 2 check boxes and path to Host application.
I added "argc argv" in the Program Arguments text box under Debug and left everything else untouched. Program crashes when run.

Comment: mmh... I don't know why the program crashes... I've tried your code and it works for me.
Can you give me your compiled executable? I'll search for problems debugging it.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3bfl2L3aMg5c3ViQ3AtNGRqQm8/edit?pli=1) This should work. And thanks. Forced to take a break from learning C because of this.

Comment: Ok solved... The problem was in the main() signature.
declare main using **argv: `int main(int argc, char **argv)`